# Данные для нейронной сети

Tags: нейронные-сети

Допустим нужно по фотке определять улыбается человек или нет. Собираем кучу фоток с улыбающимися и нет людьми. Определяем для обучения, что на выходе будем получать 1 если человек улыбается, 0 - нет. Фотки будем скармливать как массив.
Чтож теперь самое главное в чем и состоит вопрос. Размер у каждой фотки разный, то есть, нужно их подогнать под одно разрешение. И как подсказывает логика, не просто сменить разрешение, а "совместить" лица (грубо говоря чтоб на всех фото лица были по центру). Но лица разные, совместить по какой либо части лица (расстояние между глаз, ширина лица) невозможно. Тут еще куча различных цветов у каждой фотки, которые также нужно нормализовать до определенного уровня.

Как происходит подготовка данных в данном случае?
Я правильно понимаю что можно не подготавливать данные, но в этом случае, для обучения придется использовать намного больше фото?

Comment: Можно для предварительной обработки воспользоваться библиотеками для распознавания лиц (например, openCV). И вырезать фотографию с лицом. При этом полученные картинки лиц нужно сжимать, для упрощения. 256*256 хватит за глаза. Действительно данные можно и не подготавливать, но сеть получится сложнее, медленнее и, скорее всего, менее точной